# Are there any scripts to integrate social networking site's chat and posting features into a webpage

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, social-media, twitter-integration

Are there any scripts to integrate social networking site's chat and posting features into a webpage using PHP or JS... for example a section with Facebook chat, a section to post to twitter and maybe even YouTube comments.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the social network.
Facebook's developer center will help you.
http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yioiu should investigate twitter Anywhere - <strike>http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/</strike> a cool implementation of what you seek with a few lines of JS

Update: Twitter's Anywhere project is now deprecated and ceased functioning on March 5th 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some options for Google:

<strike>Google Friend Connect doesn't have a huge amount of uptake, but does have a page widget: http://www.google.com/friendconnect/</strike>

<strike>And Buzz has an API that you can use through pure JavaScript:  http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/buttons_and_gadgets.html</strike>

But... just because you can doesn't mean you should.  Think about this in terms of value to your site's visitors.  Don't do it just to be cool.

***UPDATE:***
Google has retired Google Friend Connect in favor for [Google Follows Blog](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/104226?p=getting_started_with_pages&rd=1) which uses Google Plus. Additionally Google Buzz has also been retired.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 social application from Facebook that can be used as chat/comments box.

- [Comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments) - This is a basic comment box where people will be able to add comments.
- [Live Stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream) - This basically acts as a chat box where people will be able to talk live.

The easiest way to make these work on your website or page is to download and use the their [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) kit. It's pretty easy to use and you can setup them within a few hours.